# Как вложить переменную в такое выражение?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

```
(className.match (/(^|\s)variable\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создать объект класса `RegExp` при помощи явного вызова конструктора

```
(className.match(new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + variable + "\\S+", "g") || []).join(' ');
```

Обратите внимание на удвоение символа `\`. Это связано с тем, что для того, чтобы получить строку, содержащую символ `\` этот символ нужно удвоить

```js
var str = '\\';
console.log('Length: ' + str.length);
console.log('String: "' + str + '"');
```

Comment: Точнее, _«использовать **конструктор**  класса `RegExp`»_ ;)

Comment: @yar85 А так еще точнее :)

Comment: О да, так - вообще идеально))